Correlation of a Gaussian copula
Suppose I have a 2D Gaussian copula with correlation matrix
$$
R = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho \\
\rho & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $\rho\in[-1,1]$. The Copula is
$$
C_R(u)=\Phi_R\big(\Phi^{-1}(u_1),\Phi^{-1}(u_2)\big),
$$
where $\Phi_R$ is the cdf of a 2D normal distribution with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and covariance matrix $R$. Suppose $U=(U_1,U_2)$ is a random vector whose cdf is $C_R$.
Question What is the (Pearson) correlation coefficient between $U_1$ and $U_2$?
Thoughts It should be related to $\rho$, but based on my experiments below, it's not -quite- equal to $\rho$. Is there a nice expression (or connection) between $\rho$ and $\text{corr}(U_1,U_2)$?
I calculated $\text{corr}(U_1,U_2)$ numerically using the formula
$$
\text{cov}(U_1,U_2)=\int_0^1\int_0^1 C_R(u_1,u_2) - u_1u_2\; du_1 du_2
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
\text{corr}(U_1,U_2)=12\times\text{cov}(U_1,U_2),
$$
where we use the fact that $U_1$ and $U_2$ have marginal uniform distributions on $[0, 1]$.
I then plotted $\text{corr}(U_1,U_2)-\rho$ as a function of $\rho$:


For context, I am looking for a way to construct a distribution with a given, arbitrary correlation matrix $R$, and uniform marginals. The above indicates that a Gaussian copula gets me close, but not all the way there.

I expect that the Spearman correlation of the Gaussian ($\rho_s=\frac{6}{\pi}  \arcsin(\frac{\rho}{2})$) would be what you need. If that's correct, your absolute error plot there should either be   $\frac{6}{\pi}  \arcsin(\frac{\rho}{2})-\rho$ or very close to it.

Yeah, overlaying them, they seem to be coincident. Of course sample correlations will differ and if you transform the margins the Pearson correlation will change.

To clarify, what I was claiming what that the Pearson correlation of the copula would be the Spearman correlation of the original bivariate Gaussian. I have a feeling there's very likely to be posts about this already.

Well, the formula I gave is here and here. Apparently result is due to Pearson. So that part is at least covered by previous posts.

Yep, looks like the Spearman correlation is dead-on. I didn't know about the connection between these two coefficients. Should make my searching much easier--thanks for the tip! (I'll come back and post an answer once I figure this out to my liking)

For your interest: the connection is because ranks are uniformly distributed, so the transformation to  $U$ is (asymptotically, but even for quite small $n$) close to the rank transformation.

Thomas' point is exactly the reasoning I used to arrive at the suggestion, though the mathematical proof of the actual result about distributions shouldn't need one to invoke samples and asymptotics (albeit it's very handy as a way of getting to the right function)
